# Design of REST methods for both deep and shallow insert options

Tags: rest, api-design

We are designing REST API and having `course` and `student` entities:

- course includes multiple students
- multiple courses may share the same student
- when creating course one should be able to both include already existing students(**shallow insert**) and refer existing(**deep insert**).

Which is most intuitive and correct option:

1. Have both options for providing ids and bodies on parent level:

```
POST /courses
{
  "courseName" : "Java 8",
  "students" : [
    {
      "name" : "John Doe" // new student(deep insert)
    }
  ],
  "studentIds" : [
    123, 124              // existing students(shallow insert)
  ]
}
```

2. Have both options for providing ids and bodies on child level:

```
POST /courses
{
  "courseName" : "Java 8",
  "students" : [
    {
      "name" : "John Doe" // new student(deep insert)
    },
    {
      "studentId" :123    // existing student(shallow insert)
    },
    {
      "studentId" : 124   // existing student(shallow insert)
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this only design choice for this case?

Is it acceptable to have ambiguity for JSON when fields for both id and payload are present in child entity, like in `student` entity above?

This is behind what is usually covered by REST guidelines and other asked questions here.

Comment: "studentId" :123 would be REST as it's changing the state of the course resource using another, existing resource. "name" : "John Doe" seems to be RPC. e.g. it's telling a course endpoint to invoke logic unrelated to courses, i.e. before you add this student, create them first. That's the job of the POST -> /student endpoint.

Comment: thanks @codebrane! so, what is the REST principle behind this rule - that a POST endpoint should only create parent entity, but not child one?

Comment: The API should represent the domain so a POST endpoint should create the resource associated with that endpoint, i.e. a Course. A Student is not a child of a course. It has no association with a Course and vice versa. They are "first class citizens" in their own right. What you seem to mean is an enrolment rather than a Course. e.g. POST to /enrolment (create a new one) with the Course and Student id. A Course endpoint should not be creating Student resources. It should only be creating Course resources. An /enrolment endpoint creates an Enrolment (resource) on Course 123 by Student 001.

Comment: thank you for good clarification! Really the enrollment case is straight to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as REST is concerned, both request payloads are *fine*.  REST doesn't constrain the representations that are sent across the network.

An analogy that may help: on the web, we typically send information to web servers via forms, and we've got a standardized mechanism for copying information from form controls into the request body; but there aren't any rules saying "you must design your form this way".

So if you want to mix complete representations of students with digest representations of students, that's fine.  And if you prefer to separate them out, that's also fine.

---

The right place to look for guidance isn't REST (which, again, doesn't care what your documents look like), but rather the principles of message schema design.

In particular, you'll want to be paying attention to whether or not the schema can be extended in a backwards compatible way, whether you can communicate/describe the schema unambiguously, and whether you can process the schema without ambiguity.

My guess: your life will be easier with the first schema, because you are avoiding needing to interpret whether a particular JSON Object is complete or digest - you "know" the answer to that based on which list the object is in.

Useful references on message design include:

- Greg Young's *Versioning in an Event Sourced System*
- David Orchard's work on XML Vocabularies
- Kenton Varda's work on Protocol Buffers